# How to conduct the unit test for a function defined as const in render() in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

If I have a function defined in render(), how can I add a unit test for it?

```
export class Foo extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
   ...do something...
  }

  render() { 
   const ConditionalWrapper = ({ condition, wrapper, children }) =>
      condition ? wrapper(children) : children;

   return (
     <ConditionalWrapper condition={...} wrapper={children => <div> {children} </div>}>
        <...>
     </ConditionalWrapper>
   )
  }
}
```

How can I test the ConditionalWrapper function defined in render() with jest?

Comment: question is way too broad by now. how `wrapper` HOC affects component's behavior?

Comment: I would not define my function inside the render of the component

Comment: i am just a tester :-/

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think it is possible. You have to move it outside the render method if you think of unit testing it. 
Indirect way is get the snapshots and look for certain key terms that would be created based on the condition.